# How to implement a search bar on master page ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a search bar for my ASP.NET pages that will be included in the master so it will be shown on all pages. Entering search text and hitting search will send you to results.aspx, which then retrieves the value of the text from the master page search box and displays data from the database in a grid view. Searching from my home page works fine, but I want the user to be able to enter a new search text while on the results page and have the page reload with the new data in the grid view. 
Here is the code on results.aspx page load

```
   if (PreviousPage != null)
            {
                TextBox SourceTextBox =
                    (TextBox)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("txtSearchMaster");
                if (SourceTextBox != null)
                {
                    txtSearch.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;
                }
            }
```

Code on master page

```
    <div id="search">
         <asp:HyperLink ID="linkAddFile" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Width="150px" >Add File</asp:HyperLink>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchMaster" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" PostBackUrl="~/results.aspx" />
     </div>
```

The issue is once I get to the results page and try to do a new search from there, my conditional (PreviousPage != null) says that it *is* null.

Comment: Did you try this.Master.FindControl("xyz") ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't get the search values from the previous page via `PreviousPage` property.

Instead, when the user performs a search, grab the value from the search textbox and pass the value to the results page. Example:

master page

```
<div id="search">         
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchMaster" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
     </div>
```

Master Code behind

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var searchText = Server.UrlEncode(txtSearchMaster.Text); // URL encode in case of special characters
    Response.Redirect("~/Results.aspx?srch="+searchText);
}
```

Results page code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["srch"])
    {
        //perform search and display results
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice simple approach, but be careful what you do with data you get out of a url...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not get the search values from the previous page via `PreviousPage` property.

Instead, you can also do this:

```
TextBox mastertxt = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtSearchMaster");
Response.Redirect("~/YourResultPage.aspx?search="+mastertxt.Text.ToString());
```